# Make a square matrix singular through differentiation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus, computer-vision

I have the following $4 \times 4$ matrix

$$ M = \sum_{i=1}^n P_i^T \left(I_{3x3} - \frac{x_ix_i^T}{x_i^Tx_i}\right)P_i $$

where $P_i$ and $x_i$ are $3 \times 4$ and $3 \times 1$, respectively. The $P_i$'s are camera perspective projection matrices. My goal is to optimize the $x_i$'s locally to make matrix $M$ singular.

The first approach I thought of was to try and express $M$'s determinant and then find its derivatives as a function of the $x_i$'s but this doesn't seem to be analytically doable.

Comment: Each individual term in your sum is singular, since it loses a dimension of freedom when it drops from 4 to 3. Once lost, that dimension cannot be regained. Admittedly, the sum can still be non-singular.

Comment: Do (fat) matrices $P_i$ have full row rank?

Comment: Pi's kernel is of dimension 1, it's kernel is the camera's optical axis, meaning any point through that axis projects back to the origin of the image (center). Numerical methods are welcome too. This problem boils down to making rays going through N cameras all converge to a single point in 3D, it is triangulation. The solution for that are the xi's such that M is singular and they're in a neighbourhood not too far from my initial xi's

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the row rank is 3

Comment: n usually lies between 2 and 4 typically

Comment: That information is absolutely crucial and should be included in the question. Also, it would be nice to have context, motivation and background. Hard to solve problems when one knows almost nothing about them.

Comment: What is the rank of $\sum_{i=1}^n P_i^T P_i$?

Comment: Can't tell, besides that the $P_i's$ are all of rank 3

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo You can compute the rank explicity once you're given the specific matrices but you can't say that for all projection matrices. Here I'm trying to generalize a solution for all projection matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\pi_i=(I_{3x3} - \frac{x_ix_i^T}{x_i^Tx_i})$; it's the orthogonal projection on ${x_i}^{\perp}$; thus $\pi_i$ has rank $2$ and $M_i=P_i^T\pi_iP_i$ too (because $P_i$ is surjective ad $P_i^T$ is one to one). Finally $M$ is the sum of $2,3$ or $4$ such matrices $M_i$ and, therefore, has rank $4$ in general position. Note that we may assume that the $(x_i)_i$ have a norm equal to $1$.

Let $\det(M)=f((x_i)_i)=\sum_iP_i^T(I-x_ix_i^T)P_i$.

The question you ask can be rewritten as follows: let $(h_i)_{i\leq n}$ be $3\times 1$ unknown vectors.

Problem. Find the minimum of $\sum_i||h_i||^2$ under the conditions

$||x_i+h_i||=1,i\leq n$ and $f((x_i+h_i)_i)=0$.

The idea is to construct an iterative algorithm, replacing the function $f$ with $f(x_i)+Df_{x_i}(h_i)$. To do that, we use the Maple NLPSolve; of course, we must change the constraint $f(x_i+h_i)=0$ with $f(x_i+h_i)=kf(x_i)$ where $k\in(0,1)$; one must write a little procedure that calculates a "good" $k$ (begin, for example with $k=0.1$ and while NLPSolve gives a result, increase $k$). So we are getting closer to a good solution; less than $10$ iterations suffice in general.

That follows (if you are interested) is the procedure I wrote in Maple for $n=3$; I did'nt write explicitly the cycle "od..do".

```
restart;
with(LinearAlgebra);
P1 := RandomMatrix(3, 4); P2 := RandomMatrix(3, 4); P3 := RandomMatrix(3, 4);

 W := NULL;

*values at time 0 of  y1,y2,y3 (they play the role of the x_i)

A := Vector(3, symbol = a); B := Vector(3, symbol = b); C := Vector(3, symbol = c); 

id := IdentityMatrix(3);

 y1 := RandomVector(3); y1 := evalf(y1/Norm(y1, 2)); y2 := RandomVector(3); y2 := evalf(y2/Norm(y2, 2)); y3 := RandomVector(3); y3 := evalf(y3/Norm(y3, 2));

*The beginning of the cycle "do..od"

A := Vector(3, symbol = a); B := Vector(3, symbol = b); C := Vector(3, symbol = c); x1 := y1+A; x2 := y2+B; x3 := y3+C;

L := [a[1] = 0, a[2] = 0, a[3] = 0, b[1] = 0, b[2] = 0, b[3] = 0, c[1] = 0, c[2] = 0, c[3] = 0];

res1 := Transpose(P1) . (id-x1 . Transpose(x1)) . P1; res2 := Transpose(P2) . (id-x2 . Transpose(x2)) . P2; res3 := Transpose(P3) . (id-x3 . Transpose(x3)) . P3;

res := evalf(Determinant(res1+res2+res3));

Digits := 20;

 nu := evalf(10^(-13)*(eval(res, L)+(eval(diff(res, a[1]), L))*a[1]+(eval(diff(res, a[2]), L))*a[2]+(eval(diff(res, a[3]), L))*a[3]+(eval(diff(res, b[1]), L))*b[1]+(eval(diff(res, b[2]), L))*b[2]+(eval(diff(res, b[3]), L))*b[3]+(eval(diff(res, c[1]), L))*c[1]+(eval(diff(res, c[2]), L))*c[2]+(eval(diff(res, c[3]), L))*c[3]));

s := eval(nu, L); W := W, s;

with(Optimization);

rr := NLPSolve(a[1]^2+a[2]^2+a[3]^2+b[1]^2+b[2]^2+b[3]^2+c[1]^2+c[2]^2+c[3]^2, {nu = s-0.16e-3, Transpose(x1) . x1 = 1, Transpose(x2) . x2 = 1, Transpose(x3) . x3 = 1}, initialpoint = {a[1] = 0, a[2] = 0, a[3] = 0, b[1] = 0, b[2] = 0, b[3] = 0, c[1] = 0, c[2] = 0, c[3] = 0}, iterationlimit = 10000);

y1 := y1+eval(A, rr[2]); y2 := y2+eval(B, rr[2]); y3 := y3+eval(C, rr[2]);

Norm(y1, 2); Norm(y2, 2); Norm(y3, 2);

*the end of the cycle "do..od"`
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, numerical optimization seems like the way to go, although the mathematical explanations were of great help.